# wait program for a specific time in for loop

Tags: android

I want to wait my program for 1 second every time after finishing
  `for ( j = i + 1; j <= cnt; j++)` loop.

I have used

```
  try
  { 
     Thread.sleep(1000); 
  }
  catch(InterruptedException e){ }
```

BUT my program doesn't wait every time for 1 second..It waits total 1*cnt seconds before getting sorted. Please help.

code:

```
      for ( i = 1; i <= cnt; i++) {
          for ( j = i + 1; j <= cnt; j++) {
            int id1,id2;

            StringBuilder name2 = new StringBuilder("button" + j);
            StringBuilder name1 = new StringBuilder("button" + i);
            String pack = getPackageName();
            id1 = getResources().getIdentifier(name1.toString(), "id", pack);
            id2 = getResources().getIdentifier(name2.toString(), "id", pack);
            Button bnn1 = (Button) findViewById(id1);

            Button bnn2 = (Button) findViewById(id2);

            String s1 = bnn1.getText().toString();
            String s2 = bnn2.getText().toString();
            int num1 = Integer.parseInt(s1);
            int num2 = Integer.parseInt(s2);
            if (num1 > num2) {
                bnn1.setText(s2);
                bnn2.setText(s1);
            }

        }
             //time

        try{ Thread.sleep(1000); }catch(InterruptedException e){ }



    }
```

Comment: the sleep is executed outside the for loop. So I don't understand why do you expect it to be called at every iteration. On the other hand, don't do that.

Comment: Never use thread.sleep use a handler if you want to delay. read http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html